# nest another component inside a TieredMenu

Tags: primeng

I have a p-menu in my app that contains bulk actions for a table:

[image]

Im trying to accomplish something like this when you hover over "Move to Account":

[image]

Is there a way to do this? Can you nest a p-listbox component inside a p-menu component? Or can you insert custom content into a p-tieredMenu? Or an overlaypanel with an autocomplete? Not sure how to accomplish this since TieredMenu only lets you add additional static menu items.

Comment: Based on the available properties of the menuItem, I am thinking no.